# Listening to input from another class

Tags: java, actionlistener, japplet

So I have a class that uses a `KeyListner`, when various events occur various `boolean` become true.

Now this class has a constructor, an instance of this class is called within an JApplet. Now everything works except the `Keylistner`.

When the applet is running, the `KeyListner` does not respond to any of my actions. However I know that its not a fault in my code because when I put a *main method* within the class it works fine.

So in summary,
How can I use a `KeyListner`...where all its methods are within another class. and this class is constructed within an applet.

Comment: show some code? Where did you *register* the keylistener?

Comment: I dont have the code at hand, basically its a Java game im trying to make in an applet. All the actual logic and grid is located in 1 class, and ofcourse the applet is created in another class. the difficulty for me is changing the variables located within the logic class t from within the applet its self. hope you understand that

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to call the variable from the class within the "init", 
this is why I could not successfully reference the variable. By simply creating the instance of the class from outside the "init" everything worked as expected.